# How to reshape a pytorch matrix without mixing elements of items in a batch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

In my Neural network model, I represent  an 8 word-sentence with a `8x256` dimensional embedding matrix. I want to give it to a LSTM as a input where LSTM takes a single word embedding at a time as input and process it. According to pytorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM), the input should be in the shape of  `(seq_len, batch, input_size)`. What is the correct way to convert my input to desired shape ? I don't want to mixup the numbers by mistake. I am quite new in PyTorch and row-major calculations, therefore I wanted to ask it here. I do it as follows, is it correct ?

```
x = torch.rand(8,256)
lstm_input = torch.reshape(x,(8,1,256))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct: you added a Singleton dimension for the "batch" dimension, leaving `x` to be with temporal dimension 8 and input dimension 256.

Since you are new to pytorch, here are a few equivalent ways of doing the same thing:

```
x = x[:, None, :]
```

Putting `None` in the dim=1 indicates to pytorch to add a singelton dimension.
Another way is to use `view`:

```
x = x.view(8, 1, 256)
```